# Service Worker scope and SPA navigation

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Let's say I load my website at `https://example.com`, and I register my Service Worker at `/app`.

I expect the SW to receive `fetch` events when I navigate to `https://example.com/app`.

However, if I navigate to `/app` with `history.pushState`, the SW doesn't receive `fetch` events. If I then reload the page at `https://example.com/app`, the SW does receive `fetch` events.

Does the SW `scope` not work for the History API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch` event handler in a service worker will only be invoked when there's a network request. Changing the URL using the History API doesn't trigger a network request.

Reloading a page, or entering a new URL in the navigation bar and pressing Enter, does trigger a network request.